# What is the range of $f(x) = \sec ^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1} (x)$ .

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

To find the range of this function

$$f(x) = \sec ^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1} (x)$$

I solved it like,

Range ($\sec ^{-1}(x)$) = $[0,π] $~$ ${π/2}

and, Range ($\tan^{-1} (x)$) = $(-π/2 , π/2)$

So the resultant Range will be the intersection of the two individual ranges.

So I got my answer as $[0, π/2)$, but the textbook answer is $(0,π)$. Hence my question is what is happening here and where am I wrong.

Please help me to get the fundamentals used here.

Comment: You didn't consider the actual graphs of the functions

Comment: It is by no means true that the range of $f+g$ is the intersection of the ranges of $f$ and $g$. (The domaIn of  $f+g$ is the intersection of the domains of $f$ and $g$).

Comment: Btw this idea of intersection of intervals is valid only for the domain, not range.

Comment: @Prometheus Even if I draw a graph of $sec^{-1}x$ and $tan^{-1}x$ what will be the range? Will it be where graphs of both intersect?

Comment: $\sec^{-1} x$ and $\tan^{-1} x$ have ranges that you have correctly stated.

Comment: Let me add to @Kavi's comment. Consider the function $f(x)=\sin x + \cos x$. The range of $\sin$ is $[-1,1]$ and the range of $\cos$ is $[-1,1]$. But the range of $f$ is *not* $[-1,1]$.

Comment: The best way to solve this problem is to simply plot the graph of $f(x)=\sec^{-1}(x) + \tan^{-1}(x)$. You can do this by plotting the graph of $\sec^{-1}(x)$ and plotting the graph of $\tan^{-1}(x)$, and then adding them up. If you are familiar with calculus, then it would be sensible to find $f'(x)$ so that you can find extrema.

Comment: The range of $f(x)=2x^2+1$ is $[1,\infty)$, while the range of $g(x)=-x^2$ is $(-\infty,0]$. Would you say that the range of $f(x)+g(x)$ is $[1,\infty)\cap(-\infty,0]=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, for real $\sec^{-1}x,$ we need $x^2\ge1$

$\implies$ either $x\ge1$ or $x\le-1$

Let $\sec^{-1}x=y\implies0\le y\le\pi,\ne\dfrac\pi2$  and $x=\sec y$

**Case** $\#1:$ When  $x<0, x\le-1$ and $y>\dfrac\pi2$

$\tan y=-\sqrt{x^2-1}\implies y=\pi+\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt{x^2-1})$

Set $x=-u, u\ge1,$

$$f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)+\pi+\tan^{-1}(-\sqrt{x^2-1})=\pi-(\tan^{-1}u+\tan^{-1}\sqrt{u^2-1})=g(u)\text{(say)}$$

Clearly, $g(u)$ is a decreasing function

$$g(1)=?, \lim_{u\to\infty}g(u)=0$$

**Case** $\#2:$ When  $x>0, x\ge1$ and $y<\dfrac\pi2;$

$$f(x)=\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{x^2-1})$$ which is clearly an increasing function

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yeah I got that... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

For $1\leqslant x<\infty$, the quantity $\sec^{-1}x$ increases from $0$ to (not quite) $\frac12\pi$, while $\tan^{-1}x$ increases from $\frac14\pi$ to (again not quite) $\frac12\pi$. Thus the range of $x\mapsto\sec^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}x$ on this part of its domain is $[\frac14\pi\,\pmb,\,\pi)$. For $-\infty< x\leqslant-1$, the inverse secant increases from (just above) $\frac12\pi$ to $\pi$, while the inverse tangent increases from (just above) $-\frac12\pi$ to $-\frac14\pi$. So this part of the range is $(0\,\pmb,\,\frac34\pi]$. The combined range is therefore $[\frac14\pi\,\pmb,\,\pi)\cup  (0\,\pmb,\,\frac34\pi]=(0\,\pmb,\,\pi)$.